# How to set initial value for formArray?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I need to set initial value formArray f0r my form.
Check my code:

Html:

```
            <div class="form-row form-group ingredients-drop">
                <button class="button" (click)="addAlias()">Add ingredients</button>
                <label>Kolicina</label>
                <div *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients.controls; let i=index">
                    <input class="select add-ingredients" type="text" [formControlName]="i">
                </div>
            </div>
```

TS:

```
  allRecepies: any[] = [];
  selectedMeal: any
  form: FormGroup;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllRecepies();
  }
  onChange(event) {
    this.allRecepies.map(obj => {
      if (obj.id == event.target.value) {
        this.selectedMeal = Object.assign(obj);
        console.log(this.form.value);
      }
    })
    this.editCity();
  }
  getAllRecepies() {
    this.mealService.getRecepies().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.allRecepies = data;
      }
    )
  } 

  editCity() {
    this.form.patchValue({
      name: this.selectedMeal.name ? this.selectedMeal.name : null,
      description: this.selectedMeal.description ? this.selectedMeal.description : null,
      preparationTime: this.selectedMeal.preparationTime ? this.selectedMeal.preparationTime : null,
      pictureUrl: this.selectedMeal.pictureUrl ? this.selectedMeal.pictureUrl : null,
      ingredients: this.selectedMeal.ingredients ? this.addMealArr() : null
    }) 
  } 
  addMealArr() {
    if(this.selectedMeal) {
     let a = this.selectedMeal.ingredients.map(obj => { return obj });
     return a;
    }
  }

  createForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [null],
      description: [null],
      preparationTime: [null],
      pictureUrl: [''],
      ingredients: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.formBuilder.control(this.addMealArr())
      ])
    });
  }

  get ingredients() {
    return this.form.get('ingredients') as FormArray;
  }
  addAlias() {
    this.ingredients.push(this.formBuilder.control(''));
  }
```

This is maybe bad practice but I need tutorial for my problem or stackblitz or can anybody help me ?
I need to set initial value with patchValue if it possible ? 
Or to use another method? 
I don't know just send me tutorial or change my code or set stackblitz?
I need set initial values and add new row or delete existing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can set initial values in FormGroup as below:

```
recipes = [
    {
        ingredients: [
            {name: 'Grapes', amount: 12},
            {name: 'Potato', amount: 12}
        ]
    },
    { 
        ingredients: [
            {name: 'Banana', amount: 12},
            {name: 'Orange', amount: 12}
        ]
    }
];
let recipeIngredients = new FormArray([]);
const recipe = this.recipes[0];

if (recipe["ingredients"]) {
    for (let ingredient of recipe.ingredients) {
    recipeIngredients.push(
        new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(ingredient.name, Validators.required),
        amount: new FormControl(ingredient.amount, [Validators.required])
        })
    );
    }
}
this.recipeForm = new FormGroup({
    ingredients: recipeIngredients
});
```

I have created working stackblitz example for the same
[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-umue4h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Nice but one very important thinks very..
My ingredients is array of string.. ?

Comment: Also I can't call this on init because I call it on change of dropdown but it no big problem

Comment: For array of strings you can replace object with strings, it will work fine.

Comment: change of dropdown means??, i didnt got this one.

Comment: Yes I call instead onInit I call after onChange..Example
  onChange(event) {
    this.allRecepies.map(obj => {
      if (obj.id == event.target.value) {
        this.selectedMeal = Object.assign(obj);
        console.log(this.form.value);
      }
    })
    this.editCity();
}

Comment: I will upvote just if you can set values without name and amount and where to set function call if I call it on change dropdown?

Comment: Okay can you just create working demo for the same, that will give me clear picture what you exactly want.

Comment: can you check i have updated my demo with array of strings

Comment: Friend check this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/formarray-test-try-toimplemet?file=src/app/app.component.ts
I am try to implement but I don't know how. Because I am asked here...

Comment: Most important my ingredients is array of string no object.

Comment: AND very important. I call this on select change.. no onInit

Comment: Hey i have already updated my demo with array of string, can you please confirm?

Comment: Yes Iam upvote but only little help more...First you set recipe[0].... second I need to set value only on select

Comment: Ok i will try that

Comment: check this updated link here https://stackblitz.com/edit/formarray-test-try-toimplemet-clhstu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts